# Get a Facebook user's inbox messages

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm creating a Facebook application for listing all the user inbox messages using the Facebook PHP SDK.

I used this code to get all the user's photos.

```
<?php
$facebook->api('/me/albums');
?>
```

How can I get all the user's inbox messages?

Answer (score 12):

Check their `inbox`.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#inbox

`$messages = $facebook->api('me/inbox');`

Explorer: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Finbox

Comment: as far as i remember this feature has been [removed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/inbox) since Graph API v2.4.

Comment: @KhurramShehzad seems no? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user/inbox

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been removed as of 2020.